# Paper Clip is not saving thumbnails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have the following code in the Model:

```
   has_attached_file :avatar, 
           path: ':class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension', 
           :styles=> { :original => "500x500",
                      :small => "200x200"
                   }, default_url: "icons/user.png"
```

I have also installed the imagemagick.

```
which convert
/usr/bin/convert
```

In development.rb

```
 Paperclip.options[:command_path] = %w(/usr/local/bin/ /usr/bin/)
```

I have also tried the following:

```
   Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
```

But when i try to upload the picture it only saves the original file. message from the log is:

```
[paperclip] saving user_profiles/avatars/53/original/2015-06-08-153213.jpg
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can add the below code. Don't need to worry about the  size specified in the code, you can change it to what size you need.

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: '200x200>', thumb: '80x80>' }, default_url: "/icons/user.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

In your case the convert path is /usr/bin/convert. This is the default path. So you don't need to specify this in your development.rb file. Could you please remove that and give a try.

Also make sure you have permitted params in your controller.

sample code

```
# In Controller File
private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :avatar)
end
```